# How to possible to click on button which is on behind transparent Activity

Tags: java, android

Hi stackoverflow I'm trying to click on button it is behind on transparent activity and current appear on screen this transparent activity so how it possible can you help me ?

Comment: this is not possible, only the activity that is currently used will get the touch event, so if You have a button in another activity, that is going to background, You will not reach the button

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the transparent activity (onCreate):

```
getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Comment: youe answer is good, but If i add this, i cant make touch event in transparent activity, i want both behind & transparent activity to clickable. is this possible? @Ashkan...